# $dirty property is back to true even after calling $setPristine() in the $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am stuck on something that might sounds a JS asynchronous problem. I am developing an AngularJS application, and when the user types any form data but moves to another page without saving, the app is able to ask whether s/he wants to save it before redirecting to the next page.
But, when the saving is successfully completed, the app is still asking the user whether s/he wants to save it, again (**bug**), because the conditional statement

```
if($scope[attrs["name"]].$dirty)
```

is true even after I call $setPristine in my save() function.

Here it is my directive:

```
app.directive('formConfirmation', function($modal){

    return function($scope, attrs){
       $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current){
            if($scope[attrs["name"]].$dirty){ // the problem happens right here
                /* open modal for confirmation */
                /* and checks whether the user wants to save the dirty form */
                modalInstance.result.then(function(answer){
                    if(answer){
                        $scope.save();
                    }
                });
            }
      });
   }
});
```

And my controller's save function is like this:

```
$scope.save = function(){
   /* calling a service from a factory to save the record... */
   utils.save($scope.record, function(data){
       // saving was successfully completed
       $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); // $dirty value is set to false
       $location.path('/main');
   }, function(dataError){
       // saving has failed
   });
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="myCtrl" form-confirmation>
   <!-- Form fields here -->
</form>
```

I imagine the problem happens when I change the path location inside the save function, firing the $locationChangeStart event once again. However when I check the $dirty property of my form the second time, its value is back to true even after calling $setPristine in my save() function.

I am not sure what is happening, I am learning js and angularJS, but this asynchronous javascript architecture is always a challenge. Any help, or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at dirty on the ngModel, not the attribute on the element.

Comment: formConfirmation - show please how do you use it in markup

Comment: Can I just ask why you are doing this in the first place?

Comment: @ValeryKozlov I just added it to my question. The fields are not necessary, I guess,  once they are a bunch of `<input>` tags with the directive ng-model.

Comment: @DanPantry imagine if the user fill in some details, and then accidently click on another link of my SPA, s/he will lose all the data s/he has typed in.

Comment: that doesn't mean you should set the form to pristine though, setting the form to pristine doesn't prevent loss of data, it is just used to determine if the user has interacted with the form

Comment: but I am just setting the form to pristine state if, and only if, the user clicks 'yes' in the modal (i.e. he wants to save what he's typed), aaand the save function completes succesfully